# Sets that have empty boundary

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Denote the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$ by $\mathcal{L}^2$. Let $\{E_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ be a collection of sets such that $\mathcal{L}^2(E_i)>0$ for each $i\in\mathbb{N}$. Set
\begin{equation}
E=\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}E_i.
\end{equation}

If $\partial E=\emptyset$, then is $E=\mathbb{R}^2$?

Have I missed some other candidate for $E$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a purely topological fact.

The boundary of a set $E$ is empty if and only if $E$ is open and closed. Since you require that $E$ have positive measure, it must be the case that $E=\mathbb{R}^2$.